# Inconsistent response via ping and downforeveryoneorjustme.com

Tags: domain-name-system

So I have setup this new website: [isitfor.me](http://isitfor.me)
It works fine from my browser and I can curl and ping it:

```
xMacV2:Telescope zengr$ curl -i isitfor.me
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 06:19:28 GMT
Content-Length: 639
Connection: keep-alive
```

But [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/isitfor.me) says its down. [who.is](http://www.who.is/whois/isitfor.me) also says that the domain is inactive.

What is going on? If the DNS propogation is an issue then I should also see the problem right? But I can browser the url http://isitfor.me from my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In the public DNS (the one used by your visitors and by downforeveryoneorjustme.com), the information is wrong:

```
isitfor.me.     1646    IN  CNAME http://showtee.herokuapp.com.
```

The right-hand side of a CNAME should be a domain name, not an URL.

To see the public DNS from the outside, you can use the DNS Looking Glass http://www.bortzmeyer.org/dns-lg-usage.html

Comment: But that's the only way to point a heroku app to a custom domain: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Not at all. Read the documentation you mention: it shows no URL on the right-hand side.